# How to see the downloading process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib2, urllib

When using `urllib.request.urlretrieve`, I was wondering if there is a way to see the status of the download printed in the console along with information like the file size?

Here's the code I was testing on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5.2

import urllib.request
import os


# make sure to change the directory before you test the code
directory = r'C:\Users\SalahGfx\Desktop\Downloads'

url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d8/C4D_Logo.png' 

def get_name_path():
    image_name = url.split('/')[-1]
    return os.path.join(directory, image_name)

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, get_name_path())

print('The Image has been downloaded!')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything built in. You would have to write it yourself. Luckily, it isn't too difficult. You just have to read the length of the content from the header and then read the response by chunks. Here's the code

```
import urllib2, sys

def chunk_report(bytes_so_far, chunk_size, total_size):
    percent = float(bytes_so_far) / total_size
    percent = round(percent*100, 2)
    sys.stdout.write("Downloaded %d of %d bytes (%0.2f%%)\r" % 
                     (bytes_so_far, total_size, percent))

    if bytes_so_far >= total_size:
       sys.stdout.write('\n')

def chunk_read(response, chunk_size=8192, report_hook=None):
    total_size = response.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip()
    total_size = int(total_size)
    bytes_so_far = 0

    while 1:
       chunk = response.read(chunk_size)
       bytes_so_far += len(chunk)

       if not chunk:
          break

       if report_hook:
          report_hook(bytes_so_far, chunk_size, total_size)

    return bytes_so_far

def get_name_path():
    image_name = url.split('/')[-1]
    return os.path.join(directory, image_name)

# make sure to change the directory before you test the code
directory = r'C:\Users\SalahGfx\Desktop\Downloads'

url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d8/C4D_Logo.png' 

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, get_name_path())
chunk_read(response, report_hook=chunk_report)
```

It's important to note that I used `urllib.request.urlopen` because `urllib2.request.retrieve` is considered [legacy](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface) and will be deprecated soon.

Comment: thank's for your good answer I understand now the logic behind doing it, however I know that urlopen take just the url without the filename so is it the only way to replace urlretrieve?